# Как создать файл с определенным размером?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Мне нужен файл с определенным и размером и так, чтобы в нем был валидный base64. После этой команды файл не открывается (а значит не подходит):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file.trash bs=1M count=20
```

Как сделать правильно ?

Comment: Прекрасно открывается, права на него проверьте. А чтобы там был валидный b64, очевидно, этот b64 сгенерировать и туда записать.

Comment: Поскольку base64 делает из 3-х байт 4, то **любой** размер не м.б. валидным. Уточните, Вы хотите задать размер файла с base64 или до него?

Comment: И чем вы интересно "открываете" base64. Напишите свою функцию декодирования base64, которая проигнорирует неверно декодируемый остаток и развернет все до него

Comment: `truncate` как уже подсказывают ниже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте команду `truncate`:

Из man:

```
truncate -s, --size=РАЗМЕР      установить или подогнать размер файла
                                под РАЗМЕР байт
```

Пример:

```
$ touch test.txt
$ ls -l test.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 окт 28 13:08 test.txt
$ truncate -s 1048576 test.txt 
$ ls -lh test.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1,0M окт 28 13:08 test.txt
```

Для наглядности определения base64 урезал файл до 1К:

```
$ ls -lh test.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1,0K окт 28 13:09 test.txt
$ base64 test.txt 
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
```

Answer (score 2):

```
yes AAAA AAAA AAAA AAAA AAAA AAAA AAAA AAAA | dd of=file.trash bs=1K count=20K
```

Тут важно, чтобы bs был не больше 4K, это связано с размером буфера вывода `yes`.